# get method with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var oMain = new CMain({
                       win_occurrence:40,        
                       slot_cash: 200,          
                       bonus_occurrence:15,     
                       min_reel_loop:1,         
                       reel_delay: 0,            
                       time_show_win:2000,       
                       time_show_all_wins: 2000, 
                       money:500,               
                       min_bet:0.05,             
                       max_bet: 0.5,             
                       max_hold:3,               
                       perc_win_prize_1: 50,       
                       perc_win_prize_2: 35,      
                       perc_win_prize_3: 15,     
                       num_symbol_bonus:3,        
                       num_spin_ads_showing:10 });

            $(oMain).on("start_session", function (evt) {
                if(getParamValue('ctl-arcade') === "true"){
                    parent.__ctlArcadeStartSession();
                }                  
            });
            $(oMain).on("end_session", function (evt) {
                if(getParamValue('ctl-arcade') === "true"){
                    parent.__ctlArcadeEndSession();
                }                    
            });
            $(oMain).on("save_score", function (evt, iMoney) {
                if(getParamValue('ctl-arcade') === "true"){
                    parent.__ctlArcadeSaveScore({score:iMoney});
                }                    
            });
            $(oMain).on("show_interlevel_ad", function (evt) {
                if(getParamValue('ctl-arcade') === "true"){
                    parent.__ctlArcadeShowInterlevelAD();
                }                    
            });
            $(oMain).on("share_event", function (evt, oData) {
                if(getParamValue('ctl-arcade') === "true"){
                    parent.__ctlArcadeShareEvent(oData);
                }                   
            });

            if(isIOS()){
                setTimeout(function(){sizeHandler();},200); 
            }else{ 
                sizeHandler(); 
            }
       });
    </script>
```

here is my codes. there is variable(money) inside js codes. i wanna get that variable from my mysql db how can i do it?
if it helps i can share my php file from here.
that whole online betting script i wanna add user balance in my slot game

Comment: PS: simply `setTimeout(sizeHandler, 200); ` - Since `sizeHandler` is already a function.

Comment: Aren't you missing some PHP code?

Comment: https://ufile.io/y5a5j here is my php file

Comment: What is `CMain`...? And please use pastebin.com instead of a one-click hoster. Also, if you're asking how to insert a DB value into JS, all that code is irrelevant. Just use php to echo it: `<script>var money = <?= $money ?>;</script>`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UUzQncdj

Comment: https://www.sanobet.com/slots/ thats my website. just click play button on the top u will see money area. i wanna get that balance from user balance. how can i do it?